# PyCharm can't find queue.SimpleQueue

Tags: python, pycharm

Using pycharm with python 3.7.  I am using `queue.SimpleQueue`.  The code runs fine, and PyCharm is pointed at the correct interpreter and all that.  But with this code:

```
import queue

Q = queue.SimpleQueue()
```

I get a warning "Cannot find reference 'SimpleQueue' in 'queue.pyi'".

I do some searching.  I hit ctrl-B on the "import queue" statement and it takes me to a file called `queue.pyi` in the folder `helpers/typeshed/stdlib/3/` under the pycharm installation.  So apparently instead of the `queue.py` file in `lib/python3.7/` under the python venv, it thinks I'm trying to import this `queue.pyi` file instead, which I didn't even know existed.

Like I said, the code runs fine, and I can simply add `# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences` and the warning goes away, but then the type inferencing and code hints on the variable `Q` don't work.

Another fix is to instead import `_queue` and use `_queue.SimpleQueue`, because apparently in python 3.7 `queue.SimpleQueue` is implemented in cython and is imported from a cython package `_queue`.  But importing `_queue` seems hackish and implementation-dependent.

Is there a way to tell PyCharm that `import queue` means the actual `lib/python3.7/queue.py` as opposed to whatever `helpers/typeshed/stdlib/3/queue.pyi` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fixed in PyCharm 2019.3 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-31437, could you please try to update?